# bootstrap codeigniter form input and submit button

Tags: forms, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am trying to go along with bootstrap and Codeigniter, but I am having a little problem, I cant seem to figure out how to align 3 simple elements into one row, so they are aligned perfectly next to each other.

I want my H3 tag, input field and my submit button from my form to be next to each other. I have already tried the `span4` on the 3 objects within divs, then also `display:inline`, but nothing works correctly. I dont know why, but If I want them to be perfectly next to each other, I just have to put there `margin-top: -7px` and other margins on the other objects but this looks like a not a good approach on this matter at all. Could you please help me ? !

My code:

```
<div class="well">
<h3>My superb h3 tag!</h3>

<?php echo form_open('search/quick_search'); ?>

<?php echo form_error('search_query'); ?>
<?php echo form_input('search_query','','placeholder="Search query"'); ?>

<?php echo form_submit('submit_quick_search','Search','class="btn"'); ?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

[How does it look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu8bZ.png)

Comment: Have you tried using `form-inline` for the form's class?

Comment: Yes I did, but it generates an ugly url, so I didn't go with it. I kinda did the whole thing already with sone margin tops, even though I don't like how it looks (in the code).

Comment: How/why does using `form-inline` affect the URL?

Comment: Well I was also puzzled with that so I just left it out. Maybe it was something within my application, but I am not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've been using then together (Horizontal form)

```
<?php echo form_open('search/quick_search', 'class="form-horizontal');?>

<div class="control-group <?php echo form_error('search_query')? 'error' : ''; ?>">
    <label class="control-label" for="search_query">Search Term:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo form_input('search_query','','placeholder="Search query"'); ?>
        <span class="help-inline"><?php echo form_error('search_query'); ?></span>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
    <?php echo form_submit('submit_quick_search', 'Search', 'class="btn"'); ?>
</div>      

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```